# JSII Eror When Using Inline Policy with PermissionSet

Tags: python, identity-management, aws-cdk, jsii

I am getting this error when I render this CDK in Python.
`jsii.errors.JSIIError: Resolution error: Resolution error: Trying to resolve() a Construct at /Resources/${Token[UserGroupCreation.group_permission_set.LogicalID.226]}/Properties/inlinePolicy/node..`

The code that I am running is below (CDK version 2, Python). I can't figure out how to bring in the policy object in a way that won't trigger the JSII error.

```
        group_permissionset = sso.CfnPermissionSet(
            self,
            "group_permission_set",
            name = "group_name",
            instance_arn = instance_arn,
            description = "Permission Set for Group",
            inline_policy = iam.Policy.from_policy_name(self,"group_permissionset_policy",
                policy_name = "GroupAccess"
            ),
            managed_policies = group_managed_policy_list,
            session_duration="PT12H"
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is a generic error indicating some value you supplied doesn't line up to what it was expecting (in this case) and it simply wasn't handled well by the CDK interpreter.

In the case I listed above, the issue was that  valid IAM user group was supplied, versus a valid SSO user group. The code looks exactly the same.